# Автозагрузка программы при старте сервера

Tags: java, linux, centos, автозапуск

в рамках изучения java (первый яп) написал простой эхо сервер с клиентом.

Друг дал доступ к серверу под управлением centos6 (первое знакомство с nix(?) системой).

После установки jre8 - смог запустить .jar на исполнение.

Как добавить файл в автозагрузку при старте системы?

Comment: добавьте нужную команду в конец файла `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: у меня доступ только через консоль

Comment: так этого более чем достаточно для **абсолютно полноценного** управления компьютером с unix-подобной операционной системой. собственно, с помощью *gui* **полноценно** управлять — просто невозможно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Создаем файл `/etc/init.d/"filename"`.
2. В нем пишем:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh 
   #chkconfig: 345 99 01
   #description: some code to load on boot
   case "$1" in 
        start)
              cd /root/myjavaserver/ 
              /usr/bin/java -jar java.jar &
              ;;
        stop)
              killall -v java 
              ;;
   esac
   exit 0
   ```
3. Делаем файл исполняемым: `chmod +x "filename"`.
4. Добавляем в службы `chkconfig --add "filename"`.
5. Всё должно заработать.

Answer (score 9):

если вам требуется, чтобы в конце загрузки операционной системы *gnu/linux* была выполнена какая-нибудь команда, то наиболее простой способ этого добиться — добавить данную команду в конце файла `/etc/rc.local`.

но будьте внимательны: в некоторых дистрибутивах последней строкой в этом файле идёт строка

```
exit 0
```

в этом случае вашу команду следует добавлять **выше** этой самой строки.

---

команда будет выполнена от имени пользователя *root*. если же вам требуется, чтобы она была выполнена от имени какого-нибудь другого пользователя, можете воспользоваться такой, например, конструкцией:

```
su -c "ваша команда" пользователь
```

Comment: Не знаю стоит ли заметить, что в качестве "ваша команда" должно быть указано имя bash shell скрипта, который настраивает необходимое окружение и запускает java на выполнение jar файла, а не просто имя jar файла.