# Device mapper, загрузка системы с созданием виртуального устройства

Tags: linux, boot, device-mapper, fstab

У меня задание создать виртуальное устройство над реальным с помощью модуля ядра device mapper. Виртуальное устройство должно транслировать все входящие запросы на реальное устройство, так что оба устройства должны быть как бы одинаковы.

Так как в перспективе я собираюсь контролировать запросы, я написал модуль ядра, представляющий так называемый device mapper target. Пользовался [этой](http://techgmm.blogspot.ru/p/writing-your-own-device-mapper-target.html) статьёй.

После сборки модуля, его "вставки" (команда insmod) я создал виртуальное устройство (dmsetup create). Затем монтирую это устройство и после уже могу работать через него с реальным устройством.

Но вопрос в следующем. Как запустить выше указанные команды в момент загрузки системы? В идеале необходимо использовать виртуальное устройство в качестве основного (сделая изменения в fstab, например).

Comment: расшифруйте, пожалуйста, прямо в тексте вопроса, что именно подразумевается под определением «в качестве основного».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я не силён в терминологии данной предметоной области... Могу на примере. У меня есть блочное устройство /dev/sda1. В fstab у меня прописано, что это устройство будет монтироваться как /home. Я создаю над ним виртуальное устройство с помощью device-mapper (пусть оно создано по пути /dev/mapper/my). Теперь мне надо, чтобы в системе это новое виртуальное устройство использовалось как /dev/sda1.

Answer (score 1):

как я понимаю, вам надо принудительно загрузить ваш модуль после загрузки программы *linux*, а затем примонтировать получившиееся устройство туда, куда требуется.

1. для загрузки модуля, например, добавьте его имя отдельной строкой в файл `/etc/modules`
2. если для монтирования вы используете программу *mount* примерно таким образом:

   ```
   $ sudo mount /dev/mapper/созданный-вашим-модулем-файл /точка/монтирования
   ```

   то для автоматического монтирования можно добавить в `/etc/fstab` примерно такую строку:

   ```
   /dev/mapper/созданный-вашим-модулем-файл /точка/монтирования auto defaults 0 2
   ```

подробнее смотрите:

- [`$ man 5 modules`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=modules&category=5&russian=2)
- [`$ man 5 fstab`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Однако кроме добавления модуля делается ещё команда создания виртуального устройства - dmsetup create. Как её выполнить в момент запуска системы?

Comment: @AccumPlus, тогда лучше воспользоваться [`/etc/rc.local`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576). и монтирование вызывать там же, убрав строку из `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо. Я ещё прочитал про демон udev, но пока что разбираюсь с написанием правил для него. Не будет ли лучше написать правило, которое бы выполняло скрипт создания виртуального устройства?