# Обработка событий подключения устройств при загрузке ОС

Tags: linux, boot

Установлена система МСВС3.0 с версией ядра 2.4. Необходимо настроить ramdisk (initrd) так, чтобы при обнаружении жёсткого диска выполнялся определённый скрипт.

На более новых системах ситуация очень проста. Во-первых, там ramdisk имеет тип initramfs, который настраивается через удобный config-file, а во-вторых там есть демон udev.

На этой же системе device-manager - hotplug, и то, я не уверен, что он запускается в момент загрузки системы. А ramdisk - initrd, который настраивается через linuxrc файл. Его содержимое:

```
#!/bin/nash

echo "Loading dm-mod.o module"
insmod /lib/dm-mod.o 
echo "Loading scsi_mod.o module"
insmod /lib/scsi_mod.o 
echo "Loading sd_mod.o module"
insmod /lib/sd_mod.o 
echo "Loading cdrom.o module"
insmod /lib/cdrom.o 
echo "Loading sr_mod.o module"
insmod /lib/sr_mod.o 
echo "Loading sg.o module"
insmod /lib/sg.o 
echo "Loading usbcore.o module"
insmod /lib/usbcore.o 
echo "Loading usb-storage.o module"
insmod /lib/usb-storage.o 
sleep 5
echo "Loading jbd.o module"
insmod /lib/jbd.o 
echo "Loading ext3.o module"
insmod /lib/ext3.o 
echo Mounting /proc filesystem
mount -t proc /proc /proc
echo Creating block devices
mkdevices /dev
echo Creating root device
mkrootdev /dev/root
echo 0x0100 > /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev
echo Mounting root filesystem
mount -o acl,nosecdel,secrm --ro -t ext3 /dev/root /sysroot
pivot_root /sysroot /sysroot/initrd
umount /initrd/proc
```

У меня не очень глубокие познания Linux-систем, и, честно говоря, я плохо понимаю, где здесь строка, отвечающая за определение подключённых устройств. Плюс ко всему система слишком стара, чтобы найти хорошую информацию по этим вопросам.

Содержимое config-файла загрузчика (там установлен LILO):

```
prompt
timeout=100
default=MCBC
boot=/dev/hda
map=/boot/map
install=bmp
restricted
password=Qq123456
bitmap=/boot/mcbc.bmp
lba32

image=/boot/vmlinuz-2.4.32-vniins42
    label=MCBC
    initrd=/boot/initrd-2.4.32-vniins42.img
    read-only
    root=/dev/hda2
    append="acpi=on"
```

Если эта информация будет полезна, то мне надо создать виртуальное устройство через device-mapper, которое "маппит" root-раздел.

Подскажите, что именно мне надо сделать, чтобы при запуске системы выполнялся мой скрипт?

Comment: это продолжение [всё той же серии вопросов](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616401/178576)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin :D каждый раз задачи изменяются, и я впадаю в ступор. Тут не так важно сделать виртуальное устройство, сколько выполнить скрипт при обнаружении реального блочного устройства. К слову, на свежих системах у меня всё получилось (причина описана в вопросе). Здесь я пока даже не понимаю, в какой момент подгатавливаемая корневая система становится текущей

Comment: после выполнения встроенной в [*nash*](https://linux.die.net/man/8/nash) команды *pivot_root*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin о, спасибо! Но вопрос пока не закрыт... Я вижу команду mkdevices, которая создаёт файлы блочных устройств, прописанных в /proc/partitions (спасибо за ссылку). Но, по всей видимости, никто не отлавливает их появление...

Comment: у вас же, насколько я понял, никаких «появлений» и нет. вам ведь сразу надо примонтировать в качестве «финального» root-раздела то, что предоставляет ваш модуль.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Верно. То есть после mkdevices я должен создать своё устройство и проделать дальнейшие операции, указывая именно моё устройство? Если совсем точно, то заменить /dev/root на /dev/my/device ?

Comment: судя по всему, вам надо заменить все команды, начиная с вызова *mkrootdev*, и заканчивая вызовом *mount*, на свои команды, которые в конце концов примонтируют вашу файловую систему в `/sysroot`. а дальше (начиная с *pivot_root*) пусть всё остаётся как есть. // затрудняюсь только дать рекомендации по поводу `echo 0x0100 > /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev` — не знаю, для чего служит эта команда. возможно, её тоже стоит оставить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, буду пробовать. Беда ещё - линкера нет. Могу я его перенести в образ и запустить руками? Если да, то как?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в общем, с этим рабобрался. Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо!

Comment: так напишите полноценный ответ!

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Всё проверю и напишу. Просто ответом именно на мой вопрос скорее всего будет ваш третий комментарий)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вот тут разжёвано https://static.lwn.net/kerneldoc/admin-guide/initrd.html. Та строка вероятнее всего не нужна.

Comment: @0andriy Спасибо. Но я что-то не понимаю наверное. Закомментировав всё, начиная с "echo Creating root device", система всё равно грузится нормально.

Comment: @0andriy с этим разобрался. Причина была в указанном параметре root в загрузчике. Если его убрать, то необходимо указывать **номер** устройства в файле /proc/sys/kernel/real-root-dev. Вопрос, как получить этот номер... В инете пишут, что это major*64+minor. У моего /dev/hda3 major=3, minor=3. Откуда ж там 0x0100 ? Пробовал менять - не работает.