# Не могу инициализировать проблему на debian

Tags: debian, графика, root

Год ноут стоял пылился(пока я отдавал здоровье государству), и когда уже вернулся, понял что всё то малое что знал, успешно забыл. Потыкал-потыкал,перезагрузил, и вот мой debian не запускает графическую оболочку совсем. Не обновляется, не апгрейдится и не выполняет почти ничего. Прошу помощи, совсем непонятно что делать...
startx выдает следующее:
mktemp: failed to create file via template '/tmp/serverauth.XXXXX': Read-only file system
xauth: error in locking authority file /root/.Xauthority

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Read-only file system

вероятно, из-за имеющихся ошибок, корневая файловая система (в которой, судя по всему, находится и каталог `/tmp`), была примонтирована в режиме «только для чтения».

попробуйте перемонтировать её в режиме «чтение/запись»:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

если это не удастся (или команда выполнится, якобы, успешно, но запись так и останется недоступной), вам стоит загрузить систему в режиме *rescue/recovery* (должен быть доступен в меню загрузчика) и принудительно произвести проверку файловой системы на разделе, который монтируется в корень (имя раздела можете посмотреть прямо сейчас программой `df` или `mount`):

```
# fsck /dev/имя
```

Comment: Пытаюсь загрузить rescue, через командную строку:
error: can'tfind command 'rescue'

Comment: у *grub*-а обычно есть пункт *recovery mode*

Comment: Проверил через fsck
Результатом был вывод clean
Остальное без изменений

Comment: Использовал команду mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp,запустилась графическая среда
После того, как почистил tmp, получилось обновлять систему update
Но после каждой перезагрузки приходится заново выполнять первую команду, так как startx по прежнему не запускается
Подскажите что можно предпринять?

Comment: [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576)