# Автостарт после запуска OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, opensuse

Написал программу и скомпилировал, лежит по пути `/home/vm/Documents/Debug`. Файл для запуска программы лежит в этой же дириктории и запускается при нажатии на него (`desktopBuild`).

Прочитал, что для добавления в автостарт, нужно воспользоваться уже готовыми инструментами в самом `OpenSUSE` и добавить через настройки туда свою программу.

Добавил, но никакого эффекта при запуске `OpenSUSE` я не обнаружил.
Написал обычный скрипт, который бы запускал этот бинарник `run.sh` и также воткнул его в автозапуск - эффекта никакого.

В чем может быть собственна проблема?

Comment: в винде я знаю, где находиться автозапуск, а в линуксах такого обычно нет. Есть systemd/upstart/openrc.  Так как абсолютно не понятно, как именно Вы пытаетесь запустить, и поставили ли права запуска на скрипт, и может быть оно запускается, но падает, так как не хватает прав/файлов - то сложно, что то сказать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ просто кликая на все подряд и пытаясь понять как что работает.

В настройках системы, если работать через `KDE`, есть меню `Автозапуск (Autostart)`,
добавил туда свою программу, вписал в свойство рабочию папку, запуск через `Terminal` и запуск после запуска `KDE`(выставляется в экспертных настройках). После этого, программа запустилась.

Такие функции как `rc.local` (чего не существует в `OpenSuse`), не помогут. 
Едиственное чем можно воспользоваться `boot.local`, правда не для запуска каких-то приложений, а для выполнения системных команд, выполнятся которые во время загрузки системы.