# Скрипт из init.d запускается только тогда, когда отправляешься команду reboot

Tags: linux, ssh, автозагрузка, автозапуск, orange-pi

Проблема: скрипт из init.d запускается только тогда, когда отправляешь команду перезагрузки.

Есть OrangePi с OS Armbian 5.32.1707 server.
Добавил скрипт NameScript в init.d с содержимым:

`#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python3 /../bot.py
exit 0`

После дал команду:

```
sudo update-rc.d NameScript defaults
```

Проверил работу скрипта:

```
service NameScript start
```

После отправил команду reboot, но скрипт не запустился, подкл. по ssh и отправил повторную команду reboot и скрипт сразу же запустился. Но при попытке подкл. по ssh пишет:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.*** port **: Connection refused
```

Сам скрипт до сих пор работает. Пришлось перезагрузить OrangePi по питанию, тогда доступ по ssh можно получить, но скрипт не запускается. И если снова дать команду reboot, то скрипт сразу же запускается, а ssh доступ и локальный доступ пропадают пока не перезагрузишь OrangePi по питанию...

Подскажите, в чем может быть дело? Как решить данную проблему, я уже запутался. У меня есть еще один OrangePi и там я настраивал всё точно также и там всё работает без проблем.

Comment: [этого, насколько я понимаю, вам достаточно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576), но если очень хочется именно init-скрипт, то: https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

Comment: Через rc.local скрипт не запускается. И через подправленный init также не запускается.

Comment: если вы ожидаете, что кто-то угадает, **почему** ваш скрипт не запускается, то у меня для вас плохие новости: только вы можете это выяснить. `что-нибудь >/tmp/log.file 2>&1`

Comment: Если скрипт запускать руками, то всё запускается. Через rc.local ./rc.local, либо через init, service NameScript start. И что самое интересное, что этот же самый скрипт работает на втором OrangePi без проблем...

Comment: Во-первых, что за нагромождение */bin/bash /usr/bin/python3 ...*?

Comment: @0andriy ? "#!/bin/sh" находится на первой строке, а на второй  "/usr/bin/python3 ...".

Comment: Да без разницы, вы из shell запускаете python-скрипт. Зачем так?!

Comment: А какие есть еще варианты для автозапуска Python-скрипта?