# Bash скрипты. sudo в bash скрипте

Tags: bash, shell

Привет всем.

1. Нужно написать скрипт который открылся бы вместе со стартом компьютера.
2. В скрипте нужно вызвать команду с `sudo` (Нельзя использовать `sudo ./myscript.sh`)

Пункт 2) я реализовал как-то так

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#
PASSWORD="PASSWORD"
echo $PASSWORD | sudo logkeys -s -u -o logfile.log
```

Но все же при вызове команды `./myscript.sh` он запрашивает пароль.

Вопрос: Как реализовать эти пункты.

Comment: _Никогда_ не задавайте пароли в скриптах. тем более что его передача не работает и работать не может. sudo умеет выполнять заданные команды не спрашивая пароль. Вот пример https://anton.logvinenko.name/ru/blog/sudo-bez-parolya-v-linux.html (Если этого примера не достаточно, искать в гугле по фразе "sudo без пароля")

Comment: [отпадают и вторая часть первого вопроса и полностью второй](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а метод с rc.local работает в guest режиме?

Comment: я бы, наверно, смог бы дать ответ, если бы знал, что же это за зверь такой: «guest режим».

Comment: ))я про гостевой режим ) в ubuntu