# Запустить jar при старте Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jar

Делаю вот по этому примеру.
[как сделать так чтобы при старте системы автоматически запускался jar-ник](https://gist.github.com/marlonbernardes/eef26b818270ef3b6d02)

Не работает.Может я что то не так сделал.Мое приложение находиться `/home/ubuntujava/target/blabla.jar` Помогите пожалуйста..

myapp-start.sh  (находиться в /home/ubuntujava/scripts)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntujava/target/
java -jar blabla.jar --server.port=5555 &
```

myapp-stop.sh (находиться в /home/ubuntujava/scripts)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo fuser 5555/tcp -k || true
```

myapp  (находиться в /etc/init.d/)

```
case $1 in
start)
    /bin/bash /home/ubuntujava/scripts/myapp-start.sh
;;
stop)
    /bin/bash /home/ubuntujava/scripts/myapp-stop.sh  
;;
restart)
    /bin/bash /home/ubuntujava/scripts/myapp-stop.sh
    /bin/bash /home/ubuntujava/scripts/myapp-start.sh
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Что в логах...?

Comment: @Suvitruf insserv: warning: script 'K01myapp' missing LSB tags and overrides insserv: warning: script 'myapp' missing LSB tags and overrides

Comment: Скрипт свой покажите итоговый.

Comment: @Suvitruf добавил..

Comment: [ничто не ново под луной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538005/178576)

Comment: @alexander barakin спсибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то скрипт не по [докам](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). Вначале файла должно быть что-то типо такого:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myapp 
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```