# Как запускать скрипт до авторизации пользователя?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть ubuntu с графическим интерфейсом. Есть скрипт, который необходимо запустить до авторизации пользователя и причем скрипт работает только в консоли.
Как можно сделать, чтобы при включении системы сначала запускалась консоль, в ней запускался скрипт, а потом уже запускался графический интерфейс с авторизацией?
или хотя бы как это сделать исключительно на консоли без графического интерфейс? то есть: запуск системы -> скрипт -> авторизация пользователя. Скрипт на BASH

Comment: можно в cron добавить. можно как сервис сделать, чтобы стартовал после запуска системы, можно в etc/profile.d добавить чтобы выполнился опять же после стартапа системы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576

Comment: ответ на вопрос уже есть на ask ubuntu)) [https://askubuntu.com/questions/745933/execute-script-before-login][1]

Comment: если скрипт не интерактивный, то systemd simple service подойдет

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

crontab -e

**@reboot /path/to/programm > 2&1 >/dev/null**

или прописать выше exit 0  в **/etc/rc.local**

/etc/rc.local - желательно проверить чтобы был исполняемым

Answer (score 0):

Изначально в Ubuntu была реализована инициализация в стиле [ОС Unix System V](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_V), это означает что в системе есть различные уровни выполнения [тут можно с описанием ознакомиться](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) или [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) на каждом уровне администратор может определить какие сервисы необходимо выполнить.

Начиная с Ubuntu 9.10 и выше заменили System V на [Upstart](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) тут запуск\остановка сервисов уже происходил по событиям которые генерировали процессы.

С Ubuntu версии 15.04 появился [systemd](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) в котором поделили процесс запуска на юниты - специально оформленные файлы конфигурации

Примеры запуска своего скрипта можно посмотреть на [wiki ubuntu для Upstart](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) или на [хабре для systemd](https://habr.com/post/275645/)