# Как добавить в sh скрипт в автозагрузку на Astra Linux Orel?

Tags: linux, debian, автозагрузка, astra-linux, startup

Есть startapp.sh скрипт с содержимым:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

Нужно, чтобы после запуска Астры он запускался автоматически. И для этого не нужна была бы авторизация в системе.

Как лучше реализовать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запускать скрипт до авторизации пользователя?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846982/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все проще, на астре есть "Автозапуск", который отлично работает.
Создал файл в папке с приложением start.sh, сделал на него cmod +х и с содержимым `cd /home/my_usr/my_app| java -jar myapp.jar` и добавил в Автозапуск.
Не уверен, что настоящий линуксоид сделал бы именно такую конструкцию, но сработало.