# Запуск python скрипта на ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu

У меня есть удаленный ubuntu server 16. Мне надо, чтобы на нем всегда был запущен кое-какой python скрипт. Я его могу запустить вручную через putty, но получается когда я прерываю соединение, этот скрипт останавливается. Как мне сделать так, чтобы скрипт работал всегда после запуска, даже если я оборву подключение? И как его запустить автоматически при включении сервера?

Comment: По первому вопросу - https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/11942907

Comment: По второму вопросу - https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/создание_скрипта_автозапуска

Comment: вообще несвязанные вопросы надо задавать по-отдельности, но в данном случае это не требуется: [есть дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538005/178576) (и далеко не один). кстати, вопросы не только не связаны, но и в определённой степени противоречат друг другу.