# запуск программы при включении компютера?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

***запуск программы при включении компьютера !!! Именно включении, а  не инициализации пользователя (когда включается bash).***

***При включении через СОМ порт и подгрузи баша программа отрабатывает. НО мне надо чтоб когда включился компьютер, и бо в планах не использовать CОМ порт вообще.***

---

Хотелось бы чтоб при включении компьютера, чтоб запускалась программка при включении в операционной системе Debian 9.
Я [прочёл статью](https://ualinux.com/ru/stream/avtozapusk-prilozhenij-v-linux) о том как в линуксе можно прописать запуск программы при запуске операционной системы.

Прописывать ядро я сразу отказался да и уверен там не так всё легко как написано в статье.

решил через bash :

> Самый простой автозапуск скрипта linux - это запуск с помощью bashrc.
>   Ваш скрипт или команда будет выполняться каждый раз, когда запускается
>   новая сессия терминала. Для этого добавьте адрес нужного скрипта в
>   файл ~/.bashrc:
>
> ```
> $ vi ~/.bashrc
> /usr/bin/local/script
> export MYWAR=test
> ```
>
> Здесь вы можете запускать на выполнение любые скрипты или команды.
>   Часто такой подход используется для создания псевдонимов команд,
>   объявления новых переменных и собственных функций.

Но как только я запустил этот файл едиственное что я мог это только его читать. Да и не совсем понятно куда вписывать

```
 /usr/bin/local/script # адрес скрипта
 export MYWAR=test     # имя скрипта
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Потом решил попробовать [другой вариант](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

в  файле `/etc/rc.local` прописал :

```
#/bin/sh -e
/kononov/initialization1/script_run
/usr/sbin/mescripts
exit 0
```

в файл `script_run` сделан исполняемым. он имеет одну строку`./initialization` и запускает скомпилированную программу.

Увы также не чего не вышло (((

---

Попробовал предложение @Total Pusher -а

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увы не вышло хотя и проверял как скрипт (по отдельности также не забыл сделать его исполняемым), также и  программу прогнал через `chmod +x` (когда увидел что не запустилось).

Поправил надо было в файл `nano ~/.bashrc` перед командой вызова скрипта надо было перейти в директорию `cd /kononov/initialization1` в которой всё будет происходить.

***НО увы программа запускается только кода включается `bash`.***

А хотелось бы чтоб программа включалась после подачи питания и стартовой инициализации аппарата.

---

Вот последняя итерация, прочитал [эту статью](http://tuksik.ru/auto-start-and-shutdown/) , понял что надо прописать именно в директории `/ect/rc3.d` но я не понял в каком именно файле, и бо их там шесть (`S01cron, S01dbus, S01network-manager, S01rsync, S01rsyslog, S01ssh`), а какой из них запускается последний непонятно.

---

прочитал я [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538005/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) (так сказать мой вопрос его дубликат) и понял что модераторы снова ошиблись.

всё делал по ответу

1. Создаем файл `/etc/init.d/wentilation`.
2. В нем пишем:

   `#!/bin/sh 
     #chkconfig: 345 99 01
     #description: some code to load on boot
     case "$1" in 
          start)
                cd /kononov/initialization1/
                ./script_run
                ;;
          stop)
                killall wentilation
                ;;
     esac
     exit 0`
3. Делаем файл исполняемым: chmod +x wentilation.

   **И вот тут самый прикол, в дебиан 9 нету `chkconfig`, Окей я говорю сейчас установим ввожу `sudo apt-get install chkconfig`  и оказывается его нету даже в репозитории. Только потом узнаю в дебиан 9 менеджер демонов это `systemctl` и дебиан 9 совершенно не поддерживает `chkconfig`**

Comment: Почитайте, что такое bashrc, и почитайте, как пользоваться текстовым редактором vi (вы сейчас в режиме "бибикать", а нужно переключить его в режим "всё портить"). И вообще изучите основы линукса, удивляться редактору vi это странно

Comment: Ну и вообще ничто не мешает вам открыть bashrc в любом другом текстовом редакторе, например gedit

Comment: Ок, если редакторами пока не заходит, очень часто есть GUI вариант, в этом случае также: Зайди в Synaptic найди по запросу `bum` (Boot Up Manager), далее там все интуитивно понятно, или установить с помощью терминала: `apt-get install bum` Если будут вопросы, [вот их сайт](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/bumdocs.html) или [ответ на Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374012/how-to-manage-startup-applications-in-debian-9)

Comment: @L.F.C. увы у меня нету "графония" в аппарате только КОМ порт.

Comment: @timob256 и хорошо :))) меньше ресурсов ест. Если надо, в Debian всегда можно GUI поставить, но это на любителя

Comment: @aleksandr barakin не уверен в вашей отметке.

Comment: `он имеет одну строку./initialization и запускает скомпилированную программу.` — ну ведь явно же *не запускает*. вы разве не знакомы с концепцией «текущий каталог процесса»?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  я  явно прописывал  в скрипте `./kononov/initialization1/first_init`но почему то пишет ошибку.

Comment: `.` — это текущий каталог. либо указывайте полный путь, либо предварительно смените (командой `cd /путь/к/каталогу`) текущий каталог на нужный вам.

Comment: «запуск программы при включении компьютера» полностью описан в дубликате. Хватит уже этот вопрос мучать, на него уже ответили в дубликате

Comment: Первое, что в принципе *доступно пользователю* и работает после подачи питания это *начальный загрузчик* (на загрузочном диске, флешке, CD-ROM (то что вы указываете в биосе)), который далее грузит ОС. Вот его вам и надо подменить на свою реализацию.

Comment: Вы можете как-то поправить оформление вопроса, чтобы он смотрелся вопросом, а не кучей комментариев? А то даже отвечать на него не хочется...

Comment: @PavelMayorov ОК :3  в выходные "причешу"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1.Заходим в директорию `/etc/systemd/system` в ней лежат юниты.

2.Создаём юнит `nano wentilation.service`

3.Заполняем таким кодом:

```
[Unit]
Description = Run Wentilation system :3

[Service]
RemainAfterExit=true
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/kononov/initialization1/script_run
WorkingDirectory=/kononov/initialization1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

4.Заходим в директорию `/kononov/initialization1/`

5.Создаём скрипт `nano script_run`

6.В нём пишем (скрипт просто включает программу `program`)

```
#!/bin/bash  
./program
```

7.Делаем скрипт исполняемым (находясь в той же директории которой он лежит)

```
sudo chmod +x script_run
```

*7.1. (Ненужная операция, я её из страха сделал) Возвращаемся в директорию `/etc/systemd/system` (на всякий "пожарный"). Вводим команду в вводящую юнит в автозагрузку: 
    sudo systemctl enable wentilation*

8.Стартуем юнит :

```
sudo systemctl start wentilation
```

Ух фсее :3
*Перезагружаем комп, наслаждаемся результатом.*

Вот [статья полезная](https://linuxrussia.com/systemd-create-own-unit.html), о том как писать юниты.

Comment: Зачем нужен скрипт? Почему нельзя просто запустить программу через ExecStart?

Comment: Зачем возвращаться в директорию `/etc/systemd/system` "на всякий пожарный"? Какой именно пожар тут может произойти если делать `systemctl` из другой директории?

Comment: @PavelMayorov просто хотелось результата а не постоянных ошибок вот посему я и "разбил" на такое дополнительное множество действий.

Comment: Но в ответ-то вы зачем всё это свалили? Чтобы все кто его прочтёт тоже делали лишние действия, а потом ругали "такой сложный" systemd?

Answer (score 1):

## .bashrc

`.bashrc` - это bash-файл.

Отлаживаться можно так: `. ~/.bashrc`

С символа `#` начинаются комментарии. Тут они нужны как подсказка: вам показывают как можно назначать алиасы, экспортироват переменные, ставить приглашение командной строки и т.д.

Поэтому пишите вашу команду в любом месте. Все комментарии можно удалить. А вместо них вписать `/путь/к/скрипту/скрипт`. И не забудьте сделать `chmod +x` для скрипта, который хотите запускать. Так он будет исполняемым.

## vim

Изучите как работать с vim. Или используйте другой текстовой редактор, например, `nano`.

## запускалась программка при включении в операционной системе Debian 9

Размещение команды в `.bashrc` будет запускать ее каждый раз при входе в терминал с bash. Если вам нужен однократный запуск при старте, это делается другими способами.

Comment: _Если вам нужен однократный запуск при старте, это делается другими способами._  Да при включении компьютера, должна запуститься програмка :3. Как это сделать ??