# Как добавить файл программы python (.py) в автозагрузку Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.7

Как добавить файл программы python (.py) в автозагрузку Ubuntu 18.04
Файл находиться по пути /root, наобходимо чтобы он загружался при старте сервера и постоянно выполнялся в фоне( желательно перезапускался сам каждые сутки... Спасибо за ответы

Comment: Добавьте в `systemd`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозагрузка программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538005/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416