# Как сделать что бы бот на сервере не выключался?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Учусь работать с сервером,и решил залить своего бота телеграмм на python на сервер Ubuntu.
Все установил,запустил скрипт бот работает.Но при выходе из консоли и сервера бот перестаёт работать.
Как сделать что бы бот работал самостоятельно,без моего пк на сервере?Я знаю так можно,но не знаю как

Comment: Говорю же,залил на сервер.Купил,сервер удалённый ubuntu.В этом и есть вопрос,что на сервере я запустил скрипт методом обычным python main.py работает,но при выходе с сервера он перестает работать.Сервер же и нужен для того что бы скрипты сайты боты работали сами...Как это сделать?

Comment: А как к серверу подключаетесь?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозагрузка программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538005/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) Я так думаю, что вы хотите чтобы ваша программа еще и при запуске автоматически стартовала?

Comment: Если же интересует только чтобы после отсоединения ssh программа продолжала работать, то это другое дело. Смотрите утилиты screen/tmux, nohup.

Comment: Можно в докер обернуть

Comment: Интересует что бы она работала всегда,как на хостингах это и делается)

Answer (score 1):

Для автономной работы бота можно использовать systemd.

Подробнее можно почитать тут
https://4te.me/post/systemd-unit-ubuntu/