# Нужно сделать демона на хостинге ubuntu 18

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Написал телеграмм бота на python,залил на сервер ubuntu.
Установил все нужное, запускаю скрипт вручную все работает.
Не получается сделать нормального демона что бы скрипт работал без меня на удаленном доступе.
Пожалуйста, без ссылок где описано как, у меня не получается, все время что то с ошибкой или что то другое...

Версия дестрибутива Ubuntu: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: а как вы пробуете его запускать?

Comment: По разному,как было показано на сайтах,и по всякому он либо пишет Failed to restart bot.service: Unit bot.service is not loaded properly: Invalid argument.
See system logs and 'systemctl status bot.service' for details.Либо другие ошибки

Comment: А почему вы думаете, что тут вам напишут не так как "в ссылках которые вы перечитали"? Распишите что конкретно вы деллаи и на чем возникла конкретная ошибка

Comment: Расписывать что конкретно я делал за 3 дня мне кажется долго,вы знаете как сделать демона?Могу попробовать по вашему примеру его написать поставить свою директорию(что я тоже не уверен как правильно,т.к где то говорят что нужно писать PYTHONPATH,или что то еще)и покажу ошибку.Если вы хотите мне помочь конечно)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603109/how-to-make-a-python-script-run-like-a-service-or-daemon-in-linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975624/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background-even-after-i-logout-ssh

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать что бы бот на сервере не выключался?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1173931/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%81%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nohup .../path/to/main.py > out.log &
```

А найти процесс можно так:

```
ps ax | grep main.py
```

Comment: Не понял,попробовал nohup python main.py,пишет nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

Comment: @Sexy Все ок, так и должно быть (если вам конечно в скрипт ниче вводить не надо ;)

Comment: Понял,а если мне код редачить надо,как перезапускать?

Comment: @Sexy Ну изи. Смотрим:`ps ax | grep main.py`. Киллим че написано. Потом запускаем той же командой ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install python-daemon
```

```
import daemon

...

with daemon.DaemonContext():
    do_main_program() # it is daemon main function
```

Comment: Это позволит скрипту работать на удаленном сервере без участия моего локального пк?То есть как обычный демон,закрыть консоль ssh и он будет работать?

Comment: @Sexy попробуй, я не знаю, просто нагуглил ;)